# Getting error "not an rpm package (or package manifest)" in CentOS8

Tags: rpm, centos8

Recently our AWS pipeline started failing with this error:

```
error: xdg-utils.rpm: not an rpm package (or package manifest):
```

This is where it fails in our script:

```
wget -q http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/AppStream/aarch64/os/Packages/xdg-utils-1.1.2-5.el8.noarch.rpm ​-e http_proxy=$HTTP_PROXY -O ./xdg-utils.rpm
rpm -ivh --nodeps xdg-utils.rpm
```

It started failing a few days ago. Any idea what is causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the issue was that the CentOS team has deprecated CentOS8 on Jan 31 2022 and additionally they have removed all its rpm packages from mirror.centos.org. What wget was downloading was the 404 error page so ./xdg-utils.rpm was really an html file instead of an rpm file.

This is why `rpm -ivh --nodeps xdg-utils.rpm` would later fail with `error: xdg-utils.rpm: not an rpm package (or package manifest):`.

The solution was to switch to vault.centos.org instead where all those rpms are moved:

http://vault.centos.org/centos/8/AppStream/aarch64/os/Packages/xdg-utils-1.1.2-5.el8.noarch.rpm